# Progress Dialog not Finishing - Android

Tags: android, mysql, android-asynctask, progressdialog

The issue:

Simply put, my Progress dialog continuously says "downloading data" rather than opening up the ListView populated from the MySQL database I am connecting to (through php).

Here is my code:

```
 public class Main extends ListActivity {

JSONArray jArray;
String result = null;
InputStream is = null;
StringBuilder sb = null;
List<String> cats = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    cats = new ArrayList<String>();
    new task().execute();

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list, cats));

    ListView listView = getListView();
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long id) {


            int cat_id = ((int) id);
            Intent itemIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Items.class);
            Bundle d = new Bundle();
            cat_id = cat_id +1;
            d.putString("category_id", String.valueOf(cat_id));

            itemIntent.putExtras(d);
            startActivity(itemIntent);

        }
    });




}

class task extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Main.this);
    InputStream is = null;
    String result = "";

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog.setMessage("Download data...");
        progressDialog.show();
        progressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {

            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                task.this.cancel(true);

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        String url_select = "http://www.--.com/---/master.php";

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url_select);

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        try {
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(param));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

            // read content
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        return null;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {



        String cat;
        try {
            jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            JSONObject json_data = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                cat = json_data.getString("category");

                cats.add(cat);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Categories Found",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should dismiss the progress dialog in your `onPostExecute()` method..
Eg.: `progressDialog.dismiss()`;

Comment: What a huge oversite, thank you very much.  You answered my questions so correct answer!  Now.. if only I can find out why after the dialog dimisses the ListView shows up blank....

Comment: You should also set the Adapter again to your list view or better, notify the adapter that the data has changed. you can use this: listView.notifyDataSetChanged() after you get all the data into the cats arraylist

Answer (score 0):

I dont see anywhere where you are calling `dismiss()`